# Adding a `title` attribute line break using &#10; to a JSX element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I know that I can add a line break to an HTML `title` attribute using `&#10;`, but React escapes this.

For example, here's a React component containing a standard, not-processed-by-React `title` attribute which contains a line break...

[image]

And you can see the effect in the browser...

[image]

But if React is processing that `title` attribute...

[image]

...then this is the output...

[image]

The browser console shows that this has been escaped...

[image]

How can I write a JSX element which still contains `&#10;` in the output? Or is there any other way to add a line break to a JSX element's `title` attribute?

---

**UPDATE**

I found that `\n` will add a line break if the `title` attribute is processed by React, whereas `&#10;` is escaped for the very same `title` attribute. However, using `\n` in a `title` attribute which is *not* processed by React simply outputs "\n" - in these situations I still have to use `&#10;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a react specific thing, javasricpt will see that as a `string` you may use new line charterer `\n`, which still it doesn't work if it passes through react so you can escape it in another way by encode at compile-time, and decode at run-time to achieve the desired effect.
here is a demonstration using [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in react:

```js
// %0A is URI encoded of newline character
// fellan bisar will be shown in two lines

function App() {
    return (
     <p title={decodeURI("fellan%0Abisar")}>
       behman bisar fellan ....  
     </p>
     )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

the snippet below is a demonstration in javascript:

```js
fail.title = "fellan &#10; bisar";

success.title = decodeURI("fellan %0A bisar");
```

```html
<p id="fail">fellan bisar bahman</p>

<p id="success">bahman bisar fellan</p>
```

Comment: I have another element in the same React component in which I can insert `&#10;` and a line-breal _does_ appear on the page. I can't fully explain why a line-break doesn't appear in your example but when I click "Run code snippet" I can see that the `&` has been escaped to `&amp;`. Nonethless, my point still stands - JavaScript permits line-breaks using this character but it gets filtered out in my React component.

Comment: @awj what browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox and Edge/Chrome.

Comment: Your suggestion that `\\n` or `\\t` is "normal" JavaScrript is wrong - they should have single backslashes.  
However, `\n` _does_ work. If you re-word your answer to propose `\n` instead of a decoded `%0A1 then I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @awj I'd added a react example for the solution I'd purposed, and I'm interested to know  If it doesn't show correctly in your browser still?